# Google denies the release of a production release because of the READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Tags: android, permissions, android-external-storage

I've been already denied a production release because I was using READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE. I only want to use the permission to send by email the data from the app to cover the case of the user's phone being stolen or lost.

The goal is to restore the app rapidly. As the app contains user's confidential data I've disallowed the allow backup in the manifest.xml.

```
    android:allowBackup="false"
```

My app is sending the config data (encrypted) to the user and in case the phone is lost the user uploads the data on the sdcard and re-install easily. Is there another way of doing this backup/restore technique?

Have you experienced already the deny of the google team checking the permissions? I presume they check the manifest.xml for the permissions?

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic. "Is there another way of doing this backup/restore technique? " -- if your `minSdkVersion` is 19 or higher, use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` and `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` to allow the user to choose where to create the backup and where to read it.

Comment: Interesting. I did some test. I see the interest for restore. I need to invest more time doing the backup. The big issue I see is that for something that should be easy to do it adds an extra layer of complexity. if the user gets lost in drive I'll be the drive support man. My approach has some support challenges too but it's easier to document. Having said that I'm really impressed by your reputation!!!

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience, looks like Google's automated review is getting tripped by more and more stuff nowdays.

Comment: I've requested from GPC the rules using the external storage. I'll update you as soon as they get back to me.

Comment: The only response (to my super generic Qs) I get from the gpc team is: Unfortunately I'm not able to comment on your planned implementation. frustrating...

Comment: @CommonsWare I rewind. I'm going to use it. Great tip. Thanks.